# How to automatically move specific rows to a seperate sheet based on a drop down selection?

Tags: function, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

Trying to move "Paid in full" to a seperate sheet auomatically based on the status. I'm trying to take every "Paid in full" job and take it off the tracking sheet and into sheet 2 to create a Paid in Full sheet.

(https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17F-YlSnO8nDwa7Jk54a2x4gQxPSMvnNMlvcz_PEh1D4/edit#gid=0)

Tried googling it and didn't find anything specific to this situation. Found some code, but figured there should be a function or formula to make it more simple.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Please don't expect that users must open your spreadsheet to understand your question. All the relevant information should be included in the body of the question. At present, the question assumes that the user is familiar with your scenario, your processes and your spreadsheet. Would you please edit the question to include this information in the body of the question (and also include the same data and example of output as requested by Tanaike).

Comment: One other note in regard to sharing sheets:  when you share a sheet and a column is hidden, that column is able to be displayed if someone makes a copy of the sheet in order to test formulas or scripts.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to avoid using a script, you can set it up this way:

Use Sheet1 as your data entry sheet.  If you wish, you can highlight everything not "Paid in full" to make it easier to amend your data as payments come in.

Then you can have two additional sheets - *Awaiting Payment* and *Paid in Full*.

In your *Awaiting Payment* sheet, you can use the following formula to display all transactions that **HAVE NOT** yet been paid in full:

> =FILTER(Sheet1!A4:N,NOT(Sheet1!E4:E="Paid in Full"))

In your *Paid in Full* sheet, you can use the following formula to display all transactions that **HAVE** been paid in full:

> =FILTER(Sheet1!A4:N,Sheet1!E4:E="Paid in Full")

But in order to "move" the data as you propose, you will need a script.